# Objective-C File won't display (Xcode)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I am building an iOS app in Swift, but am also using some Objective-C files from a different project. After adding them to the project, I can't view the code in the files: depending on whether it is a .h or .m, I will only see a paper with an h or an m. Also, my project is stuck in indexing. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you try restarting Xcode?

Comment: Twice, plus restarting the computer.